# I am getting this error with laravel scout: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I'm getting this error while installing Laravel Scout:

Problem 1
- laravel/scout[v9.1.0, ..., 9.x-dev] require illuminate/bus ^8.0 -> found illuminate/bus[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/scout ^9.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/scout[v9.1.0, 9.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your composer you have `"laravel/framework": "^7.29",` wich is equivalent to `>=7.29 <8.0.0` but you're requiring `illuminate/bus[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev]` wich is part of `laravel/framework >=8.0.0`

So, you can't install laravel scount version >= 9.0

try installing version 8.6.1 wich is compatible with laravel 7.x with the command:

`composer require "laravel/scout:^8.6.1"`

Comment: @ANWARHOSSAIN wich command were you using to get this error ? are you installing laravel scount directly or installing another package that requires laravel scout ?

Comment: I was using this command: composer require laravel/scout

Comment: then run `composer require "laravel/scout:^8.6.1"`

Comment: Thanks brother, it has been installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should just install ext-xml

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```